# React JS render conditionally if type is video or type is image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a coding challenge and i'm trying to fetch Imgur post from Imgur API and i'm trying to render images videos or gif.  When i receive the data i get an image array which has information about the image which can be of "type" 'image/png or jpeg' gif or video. I'm trying to render them conditionally in case type is video i want to render a video element or image element because when i render only images i get empty photos

```
return (
    <div className={styles.ImgurPost}>
      <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
        {image.images && image.images[0].type.startsWith("video")}
        <video className={styles.video} src={image.images[0].link}></video>
        {/* <img className={styles.image} src={image.images[0].link}></img> */}
      </div>
      <div className={styles.info}>
        <p className={styles.description}>{image.title}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

This is the api return and it includes a "type"

```js
account_id: 94569445
account_url: "DumpsterKoala"
ad_config: {safeFlags: Array(4), highRiskFlags: Array(0), unsafeFlags: Array(0), wallUnsafeFlags: Array(0), showsAds: true, …}
ad_type: 0
ad_url: ""
comment_count: 74
cover: "UIkJ0L6"
cover_height: 1323
cover_width: 1757
datetime: 1659932020
description: null
downs: 20
favorite: false
favorite_count: 33
id: "CS5NoBO"
images: Array(1)
0: {id: 'UIkJ0L6', title: null, description: null, datetime: 1659932007, type: 'image/jpeg', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
images_count: 1
in_gallery: true
in_most_viral: true
include_album_ads: false
is_ad: false
is_album: true
layout: "blog"
link: "https://imgur.com/a/CS5NoBO"
nsfw: false
points: 423
privacy: "hidden"
score: 441
section: ""
tags: (2) [{…}, {…}]
title: "It do be like that"
topic: null
topic_id: null
ups: 443
views: 36223
vote: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conditionally render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) using [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator

```
return (
<div className={styles.ImgurPost}>
  <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
    {image?.images?.[0]?.type && image.images[0].type.startsWith("video") ?
    <video className={styles.video} src={image.images[0].link}></video> :
    <img className={styles.image} src={image?.images?.[0]?.link}></img> }
  </div>
  <div className={styles.info}>
    <p className={styles.description}>{image.title}</p>
  </div>
</div>
);
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'). image.images array has more than 1 item so i'm only accesing the first one but i still get the error above

Comment: I have updated the solution with [optional chaining](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/optional-chaining-in-es7-and-support-in-react-js/), please check if that works for you.

Comment: It worked thank you man , so basically the "?" just does actually check if it doesnt exist ?

Comment: Yes, check this [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or the other doc I posted above. Another way to check is `image && Array.isArray(image.images) && image.images.length > 0 && image.images[0].type && image.images[0].type.startsWith("video")`

Comment: Okay thank you , very helpful , hope to get more answers from you as i am new to react and i've only used vue js

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<object />` tag it will take care of the format for you